# Setting Priority for Bluetooth Auto connection

Tags: android-bluetooth

I am currently working on bluetooth auto-connection. I wanted to know how can I set priority 0 for the last connected device so that in the next auto connection the system tries to connect with this device first always.

I wanted to know where to make these changes in android source code.

Comment: Do not understand your question, it already works in this way. Files are platform/packages/apps/Bluetooth/src/com/android/bluetooth/btservice/ PhonePolicy.java and BondStateMachine.java. 0 is `PRIORITY_OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this guide form Android:

https://source.android.com/devices/automotive/ivi_connectivity

You can not customize which device to be connected first and which to be connected last but you modify existing policy or write your own custom policy to handle how many and which devices should be connected on next reconnection.